# MASS::mvrnorm: is the diagonal of argument "Sigma" variance or standard deviation?

Tags: r, statistics

```
 library(MASS)

 mvrnorm(n, mu, Sigma)
```

Is the diagonal element of argument `Sigma` variance or standard deviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?MASS::mvrnorm`

```
Sigma: a positive-definite symmetric matrix specifying the
      covariance matrix of the variables.
```

So diagonal elements are variance. See [wikipedia: covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).